# Pricing Kaorti Resin Spinning Swords

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, dnd-3e

I am considering getting a Spinning Sword made from Kaorti Resin for a character in an upcoming game.  She is a Medium creature, though depending on how things go I may get the Monkey Grip feat so I might want a Large sized version of the weapon.

EDIT: I am hoping to purchase the item as a PC, not craft the item myself.  Thus, it would be an NPC spending the XP, I can never seem to find the cost for paying an NPC to spend the XP for something like this.

1. What would the cost be for a regular Kaorti Resin Spinning Sword?
2. What would the cost be for a Masterwork Kaorti Resin Spinning Sword?

   - The Spinning Sword (Secrets of Sarlona p136) costs 50g.
   - The process to make a Kaorti Resin item permanent costs the Kaorti Armorer crafting it 50% of the appropriate Masterwork item cost. (for a weapon that means 150xp)

Lastly, what would be the cost for a Large version of each?

NOTE: 3.0 is not allowed in this game, however Fiend Folio is technically 3.0 and was updated to 3.5 with a free booklet put out by the WotC apparently.  For the sake of this question I am assuming that web supplements as well as this booklet (and thus Fiend Folio) are approved for use.  The booklet does not change anything regarding the Kaorti entry in FF.  Tagged with 3.0 because Fiend Folio is still considered 3.0 in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Size changes the cost of the base weapon.

> [The weapon’s cost in the table] is the same for a Small or Medium version of the weapon. A Large version costs twice the listed price.

<sup>[SRD > Equipment & Special Materials > Weapons > Cost](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#cost)</sup>

Masterwork costs do not change with size or material.

> The masterwork quality adds 300 gp to the cost of a normal weapon.

<sup>[SRD > Equipment & Special Materials > Weapons > Masterwork Weapons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#masterworkWeapons)</sup>

So a Medium *ribbon spinning sword* would cost 350 gp, and therefore costs the kaorti who makes it 175 XP. A Large version would cost 400 gp, so 200 XP.

Typically, [paying for services that cost the provider XP cost 5 gp per XP the provider loses](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/41105/4563), so multiply these XP costs to find their value to you: 875 gp for the 175 XP of the Medium *ribbon spinning sword*, 1000 gp for the 200 XP of the Large *ribbon spinning sword*.

As an aside, increased weapon size category is an *extremely* ineffecient way to improve your damage, and Monkey Grip in particular is an exceptionally expensive option for that bonus. Note that the greater base damage of the weapon is the *only* advantage that a larger weapon offers; reach, for example, is defined by *your size*, not the weapon’s size.

Comment: Wasn't going for damage, was going for increased range.  And I was referring more to the cost to a non kaorti who purchased the item from a kaorti npc, I apologize for not clarifying that.

Comment: @Dorian Weapon size does not affect reach; only your size affects that.

Comment: I thought for a reach weapon it does affect the reach?  Like a whip or a spiked chain.  *Spinning Swords* are considered 1h reach weapons that can also hit adjacent squares.

Comment: @Dorian No. The reach of reach weapons is affected by your size, but not by their own size.

Comment: @Dorian About the reach issue, this [question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47227/8610) may interest you. The spinning sword is even mentioned.